# Is it common use case to use Angular 4 or React to build sections of a website?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, mvvm, asp.net-core

I have to start by saying that I studied Angular 4 but I have not used it for any real projects and I don't know nothing about React. With so many technologies available I feel a little confused on when and how to use them. I have a website that I built using asp.net core. The website is a store that shows objects for sale and enable users to add and modify their products. The site is a MPA that eventually (not to say often) uses Ajax to make the application more dynamic and fast to load. I was thinking about turning the control panel that enables users add/modify their products, and uses a lot of javascript/jquery code to support those tasks, into SPA using React or Angular to make the website navigation more pleasant. Is this approach of using React and Angular in a section of website a good idea or Angular or React should only be used on the entire site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can combine React or Angular components with just regular website, especially when you want to rework complicated logic, which is better to do with such frameworks. You can also see how it works in action, reworking small components and decide if it worth.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that it is a common practice, combining Angular 4 with React or the other way around. It is true that you can use React components in a Angular application but not the other way around.

Its really something you have to consider for yourself, usually you decide to take full advantage of a specific framework. Personal preference and or the preference of the people you are working with usually determine this.

All of this is very much based on ones own opinion.

Comment: I don't want to combine React with Angular. I want to have sections of a web site that are SPA(Angular OR React) and sections that use full page requests.

Comment: So you are never combining them in the single page application? Then why would you want to do something outside of a single page application when you're already using it? You might aswell take full advantage and do everything in the single page application, rather than generating or serving only html next to the single page application.

Comment: Because I don't like pure SPA websites, I think no one like them.

Comment: You can just use plain HTML in parts of the SPA.